# Result of Hive unbase64() function is correct in the Hive table, but becomes wrong in the output file

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

There are two questions:

1. I use `unbase64()` to process data and the output is completely **correct** in both `Hive` and `SparkSQL`. But in `Presto`, it shows:

[image]

2. Then I insert the data to both local path and `hdfs`, and the the data in both output files are wrong:

[image]

The code I used to insert data:

```
insert overwrite directory '/tmp/ssss'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
select * from tmp_ol.aaa;
```

My question is:
1. Why the processed data can be shown correctly in both `hive` and `SparkSQL` but `Presto`? The Presto on my machine can display this kind of character.

2. Why the data cannot be shown correctly in the output file? The files is in `utf-8` format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CAST (AS STRING) over output of unbase64() function.

````
spark.sql("""Select CAST(unbase64('UsImF1dGhvcml6ZWRSZXNvdXJjZXMiOlt7Im5h') AS STRING) AS values FROM dual""").show(false)```
````